# C - how to modify an array of pointers inside of a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I'm trying to implement a hash table in C, and almost have it. I'm implementing collision resolution via chaining using a linked list in each array slot, and I'd like to be able to chain inside a function call.

Now, the problem is that in order for the modifications to be permanent I believe that I need an additional level of indirection.  This is a problem in that when I try to traverse the list the previous element is overwritten by the next (see my comment inside the insert() function).  I've tried to pass this array with an additional level of indirection specified a few different ways but I get compiler warnings and seg faults.

This may seem simple to some of you, but it's had me scratching my head for quite some time now, and this scenario (passing array of pointers for modification) is treated nowhere in my text and I can't seem to find this exact question asked (although it may be in a form I don't recognize).  I'm not necessarily looking for a 'quick fix' to my code, but I want to understand what is the best practice to accomplish what I'm looking to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
//#include "list.c"
struct node{
    int key;
    struct node* next;
};

void createTable(struct node *table[], int numEls, int numSlots);
int hash(int key, int numSlots);
void insert(struct node *table[], int key, int slot, int numSlots);
void display(struct node *table[], int numEls);

int main(void){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int numEls, numSlots;
    printf("Please enter the desired number of slots in the hash table: ");
    scanf("%d", &numSlots);
    struct node *table[numSlots];
    printf("\nPlease enter the desired number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &numEls);
    printf("\nYour load factor will be %f", (float)numEls/numSlots);
    createTable(table, numEls, numSlots);
}

void createTable(struct node *table[], int numEls, int numSlots){
    for(int i = 0; i < numSlots; i++)
        table[i] = NULL;
    for(int j = 0; j < numEls; j++){
        for(int k = 0; k < 99999999; k++){}//give the rand function time 
        int el = rand()%100;
        insert(table, el, hash(rand()%100, numSlots), numSlots);
    }
    display(table, numSlots);
}

int hash(int key, int numSlots){
    return((int)(pow(key, 2.819)) % numSlots);
}

void insert(struct node *table[], int key_, int slot, int numSlots){
    printf("\nInserting %d into slot %d", key_, slot);
    fflush(stdout);
    struct node* new = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    (new)->key = key_;
    (new)->next = NULL;
    struct node** temp = &(table[slot]);
    if((*temp) == NULL){
        printf(" (*temp) == NULL");
        (*temp) = new;
    }
    else{
        printf(" %d", (*temp)->key);
        while((*temp)->next != NULL){
            printf(" %d", (*temp)->next->key);
                (*temp) = (*temp)->next;  //head is overwritten with head->next 
        }
        (*temp)->next = new;
        printf(" %d", (*temp)->next->key);
    }
}

void display(struct node *table[], int numSlots){
    for(int i = 0; i < numSlots; i++){
        printf("\nSlot %d:", i);
        struct node* temp = table[i];
        while(temp != NULL){
            printf(" %d", temp->key);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you "giving the rand function time"? I think that's a misunderstanding on your part and is definitely not necessary to generate successive random numbers. And you presumably should be passing `el` to `hash`, not the next random number in the pseudo-random sequence.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using pointers to pointers? i.e. why not pass table around as 'struct node table[]', which is itself a pointer to the first node in table, and in insert use 'struct node* temp' instead of 'struct node** temp'? That would make it easier to debug IMO.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my duplicated efforts with el and the superfluous rand() call.  I did remove the loop and indeed, it seems that my assumption about the pseudorandom number generator was incorrect.

Comment: Please provide sample input that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @sjeohp: I've tried to remove the extra level of indirection but my modifications to the elements of the linked list are lost when I do this.

Comment: @merlin2011:  You can simply chose 3 slots and 13 elements, for example, to see the problem.  Any combo that is likely to generate > 2 collisions will reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user3602820, I have reproduced your problem, and I believe I have corrected it. Please try the version in my answer and see if it fixes the problem. Note that I did not try to debug any of your other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line with the comment, you are overwriting the *pointer* to the head (inside the outermost array) with the next element in the linked list, which was probably not your intent.

The correction is to walk down the list of pointers until you found the last pointer, without modifying the main data structure during the walk.

Here is a corrected version of `insert()`.

```
void insert(struct node *table[], int key_, int slot, int numSlots){
    printf("\nInserting %d into slot %d", key_, slot);
    fflush(stdout);
    struct node* new = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->key = key_;
    new->next = NULL;

    // Here we make a copy of the pointer to the head node in the linked list.
    // This way, we never overwrite the original copy which lives in the array itself.
    struct node* head = table[slot];
    if(head == NULL){
        printf(" head == NULL");
        table[slot] = new;
    }
    else{
        while(head->next != NULL) {
            head = head->next;  //head is overwritten with head->next 
        }
        head->next = new;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely correct, and I thought that I tried this but apparently not.  Thank you.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem now: you have table[slot] = new, where I had head = new when I was trying with single pointers.

Comment: @user3602820, Oh I guess that's what you were trying to accomplish by using the `**`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer but is too big for a comment...  can you explain what this code is meant to be doing?

```
while((*temp)->next != NULL)
{
    printf(" %d", (*temp)->next->key);
    (*temp) = (*temp)->next;  //head is overwritten with head->next 
}
(*temp)->next = new;
```

I would expect that you want to append the new node at the end of the linked list of existing nodes in this slot.  But this code actually updates the head to point to the last node in the list , just like your comment says (leaking memory - the earlier nodes in the list are now unreachable). Then it makes the last node (which is now the only node in the list) point to `new`.

So your "list" only ever has length 1 or 2, and it leaks memory each time you try to put a third entry in.

It seems to me that there is nothing wrong with your passing of `table` (which is a list of heads of linked lists) but the problem is that the code that maintains the list for which those are heads, is not right.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  Merlin beat you to it, but this is the problem.  I was unsuccessful with the use of single pointers because of my attempt at assigning to the first pointer in the array (d'oh!)